# Heroku Procfile for WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, heroku, foreman, procfile

I'm setting up a WordPress blog on Heroku.  When I run `foreman start` to run the site locally, I get an error about a missing Procfile.  I've written Procfiles for Python web apps, but I'm on unfamiliar ground with PHP.  What should go in a Procfile for a WordPress app?  Thanks much.

Comment: This blog post has suggestions: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the [default PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php), the default Procfile would look like this:

```
web: sh boot.sh
```

You can figure this out from any buildpack by looking at the `default_process_types` entry (if defined) in [`bin/release`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/59f512ee542d4954bda188af0d2f7e7c1109abc4/bin/release#L7).

I should note that this assumes that `bin/compile` has been executed (just like the buildpack would do when pushing to Heroku) prior to running the Procfile. The PHP buildpack is a bit of a special case because `boot.sh` gets [generated in `bin/compile`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/59f512ee542d4954bda188af0d2f7e7c1109abc4/bin/compile#L49-L63), so you need to make sure you actually have a `boot.sh` on your local machine too that launches Apache and PHP.